# Linux: MPC current song output

Tags: python, linux

I try to make custom output on my internet Radio. (mpd/mpc)

getInfo.py:

```
#!/bin/bash
opt=$@
mpc $opt &> /dev/null

station="`mpc --format \"[%name%]\" | head -n 1`"
title="`mpc --format \"[%title%]\" | head -n 1`"
vol="`mpc | head -n 2 | tail -n 1 | awk {'print $4'}`"

echo $station
echo $title
echo "Volume: "${vol//[()_]/}
```

And save output witch wach -n getInfo.py > radio.log

Output format is here:

```
Amazing Smooth and Jazz
Koop - Koop Island Blues
Volume: 100%
```

So i need each time when output changes show output on shell.
How to do that?

Comment: Not directly related to you question, but why do you have a .py extension for you bash script?

Comment: Related to your question: you could use watch to regularly display the output in a shell...

Comment: But i need only output when something in ouput changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To get you started:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE

last_output = ""
while(1):
    proc = Popen(["mpc"], stdout=PIPE)
    output, retval = proc.communicate()
    if not output == last_output:
        print(output.decode('ascii'))
    last_output = output
```

I will leave fine-tuning the output to you.

Comment: How to format it? I can`t use comands like mpc | head -2 in popen. It is possible?

Comment: I am sure it is possible somehow, but unfortunately, I don't know how to chain pipes from python. You already have a bash script that creates the output you need - try to call that instead of mpc from popen.

Answer (score 2):

If you're only looking for the song output to update when changed, `mpc` has the command `current` that has a `--wait` option that tells mpc to block until the next song before displaying the result, this allows you to loop on it.  From there you can update whatever software you want with it.

For example:

`while :; do notify-send --urgency=low -i "audio-headphones" "$(mpc current --wait)"; done &`